# НЕ или НИ в местоимениях и наречиях?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Ужасно путаюсь с этими частицами в оборотах типа "ни(не) при чем"? Как их наконец запомнить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В отрицательных и неопределенных местоимениях и наречиях без ударения пишется И, под  ударением Е. Поэтому "н**и** при чём", "н**и** за чЕм", но "н**Е**зачем" (ударение на первый слог). Так правильное написание помогает нам быстро понять, что именно написано.

Answer (score 0):

Ужасно путаюсь с этими частицами в оборотах типа "ни(не) при чем"? Как их наконец запомнить?

В отрицательных и неопределенных местоимениях и наречиях без ударения пишется И, под ударением Е. Поэтому "ни при чЁм". Кроме того, можно запомнить, что все отрицательные и неопределенные местоимения и наречия пишутся слитно или в три слова, но никогда раздельно.. Например, "НЕчего", но "ничегО";"нЕ к чему", но "ни к чЕму".